# google map and bing map Pan, Zoom not working on Windows Phone 7.5(Mango) for web application

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1

I am creating a web application targeted for windows phone 7.5(Mango) with a map(Google or Bing which one will work best for me). It seems panning through swap and zoom through pinch is not working for google map and bing map. Pan and zoom works through buttons provided on the map. I need to know that there is work around to provide zoom through pinch or it is the mango limitation.

Thanx

Comment: Why aren't you using the build-in map control, rather than a embedded WebBrowser control?

Comment: How can I use built-in map control in web app? I don't think it is possible.

Comment: That's the thing. Why are you making a web-app in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to work I'm afraid. When you pinch or pan within the WP7 browser, these interactions are translated into pinch / pan on the browser 'surface'. As a result, the JavaScript within the page does not receive these events. The only way to support this would be to 'intercept' the manipulation events, then feed that to the JavaScript code on the web-page (as described in [this blog post](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/)). However, this requires native code - so isn't much good for a purely web-app.